# Call typescript from javascript and viceversa

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Here is the issue...
I first had some libraries that have their d.ts files so i was able to use them in an angular2 project, but i dont have the d.ts for some others, and also the libraries from the opensource repository are not complete or are not updated for the newer version of the .js libraries that i wish to use.

So I want to try the same operation but in opposite direction, like i have some restrictions due to angular2 ... I am able to include directly javascript to an html page, and the angular2 environment will be triggered as always.

Let me post some code so you undestand better:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Angular 2 QuickStart</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
<script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.2.2/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
<script>
System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<my-app>Loading...</my-app>
<!-- Here my custom javascript that will create some controls under body-->
<script>
<!-- this script will create some custom controls-->
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

So as you see the angular will be configured and loaded as alwasys but my custom javascript will be also executed.

I want to communicate from that javascript that is at the bottom in the page with
the angular2 components/modules

Any ideas?????????

Sothing weird i imagine is to create a hidden div where i store my json and the use it to comunicate with the components/modules... it is to dirty but you may have some better ideas!!!!!!

Comment: does the Javascript you want to include just defines classes/functions that you want to access from your components? Or is it a running script that actively "does" stuff?

Comment: I don't understand what problem you have. Please consider rephrasing your question to make it clearer.

Comment: @BeetleJuice well actually is a full library, google maps library. (some body will say) "but why u dont use Angular2-google-maps"  for the simple reason that it is not complete and it has bugs, and is not google certified.   but by your question i think u will suggest to do myself the definition file so i can use it in typescript???  but for these huge libraries it will take too much time... :( ....

Comment: @Alex this is the simple question "I want to communicate from that javascript that is at the bottom in the page with
the angular2 components/modules"

Comment: Does the library have a primary object class through which you make calls?  For instance, some charting libraries have a `Chart` object through which you use the library with `new Chart()`, `Chart.draw()`, `Chart.update()`...  If your library has such a main entry point, there could be a simple solution.

Comment: @BeetleJuice ok, so what would you suggest if the library is how you describe?

Comment: Take a look at my answer. I shared how I solved a similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry i didnt't update the code so here is the solution:
You will registers callbacks at global scope to comunicate to angular2, the update from typescript component to javascript is easy we just call this callback that is register at global scope, but calling the callback from javascript to update the angular2 component is a little bit tricky but i leave you here the conde of a component:

```
export class MyComponent {
    selectedData: any;

    constructor(private _ngZone: NgZone,
        private elementRef: ElementRef) {
        this.title = this.companyName;
    }

    public updateDataAction = (data: any) => {
        this._ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
           this._ngZone.run(() => {
               this.selectedData = data[0].value[3];
           });
        })
    };

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        sendMessage(this.updateDataAction);
    }
}
```

Take in count that SendMessage is a global method, i mean registered in global scope and of course you need to add the definition in d.ts file
like this:

declare function sendMessage(callback: ((message: string) => void)): void;

BEAUTIFUL ISN'T IT???
a piece of art

Answer (score 0):

Use the Google Maps web component. https://github.com/GoogleWebComponents/google-map Angular2 was built with Web Components in mind. The power of web components is it they expose an interface that can be accessed from any framework, toolset or plain old javascript.

Here is an example of using a mapping Web Component within Angular2:
https://technology.amis.nl/2016/02/10/how-to-use-polymer-webcomponents-in-angular2/

**Update**

Or if you really need the Google Maps javascript API just create a provider that returns the the `window.google.maps.Map` object so that you can call it directly in your components or services.

Another option is to just use this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-maps

Comment: Nicce try bu first, those example failt with Angular2 rc6, the Google-Map library cant be loaded using Bower even forcing ti , even the paper-button . :(

Answer (score 0):

Jherzon, I'll explain how I integrated a 3rd-party charting library.  Hopefully it will help you; just replace references with your library and its main object class:

- Add library in the `dependencies` in `packages.json`. I added `"chart.js": "2.2.1"`
- Run `npm install` to install the library as an NPM module
- Add the library to SystemJS packages.  Here is an excerpt of my `systemjs.config.js`:

.

```
// map tells the System loader where to look for things
var map = {
    'app':                        'dist',
    'rxjs':                       'node_modules/rxjs',
    '@angular':                   'node_modules/@angular',
    'chart.js':                   'node_modules/chart.js/dist',
};
// In packages, add a reference to the JS file with the 3rd party lib
var packages = {
    'app':                        { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'chart.js':                   {main:'Chart.js', defaultExtension: 'js'},
};
```

- Since there are no typescript definition files with the library, the compiler will throw errors all over the place. So I added a file called `custom.typings.d.ts`. It contains the line below (replace `Chart` with whatever the main object class is in your 3rd-party lib):

.

```
declare var Chart:any;
```

- And, I added a reference to that file, so typescript will see the declaration and not complain when I access methods and properties of the object class. In `main.ts` I have:

.

```
///<reference path="./path/to/custom.typings.d.ts"/>
```

- Once all that is setup: In any component that uses charts, I import the library as I would any other class dependency with:

.

```
import 'chart.js'; //replace with the SystemJS's map property name used above
```

Your paths may vary, but that's basically my setup. Now, use the library as you wish. For me it was:

```
let oChart = new Chart(this.chartOptions);
```